Enforce git tags with specific formatting
I'm working on a shared project that uses git as version control.
I'd like to avoid other developers creating tags in the project that contain special characters like newline since it break the complication command syntax when the tag is added there.
In fact, i want to enforce tag name formatting to contain only alpha-numeric characters, and the char '_'. How can I force this repo not to accept any tags that are not compliant with this standard.
Is there such option in Gitlab ?

Check the Gitlab documentation. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/tags/ There seem to be some options to trigger CI/CD checks when anyone pushes a new tag to the repo. I'd prefer to specify who is allowed to create a tag, so a few senior people like a release manager can maintain control over the formatting.

As for the first part of your question about disallowing tags with newline characters, Git doesn't allow tags with newline or other whitespace characters in the name.
You can test it yourself:
$ git tag $'foo\nbar'
fatal: 'foo
bar' is not a valid tag name.
$ git tag 'foo bar'
fatal: 'foo bar' is not a valid tag name.

This is actually handled by the plumbing command git-check-ref-format. The docs state:

Git imposes the following rules on how references are named:

They can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot . or end with the sequence .lock.

They must contain at least one /. This enforces the presence of a category like heads/, tags/ etc. but the actual names are not restricted. If the --allow-onelevel option is used, this rule is waived.

They cannot have two consecutive dots .. anywhere.

They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values are lower than \040, or \177 DEL), space, tilde ~, caret ^, or colon : anywhere.

They cannot have question-mark ?, asterisk *, or open bracket [ anywhere. See the --refspec-pattern option below for an exception to this rule.

They cannot begin or end with a slash / or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the --normalize option below for an exception to this rule).

They cannot end with a dot ..

They cannot contain a sequence @{.

They cannot be the single character @.

They cannot contain a \.



For the second part, it appears Gitlab does not support that.
A possible workaround would be to create a protected tag rule with the pattern you want, then just periodically delete all but the protected tags.
Example - Periodically Remove All Tags
Provided you have protected tags correctly, it should be safe to trigger deletion all tags, because Gitlab should prevent deletion of protected tags matching your pattern.
Here's a shell quickie to delete all remote tags in a git repo (this should work on any Git hosting platform, including local clones):
# Make sure all remote tags exist locally so we can iterate over them
git fetch --tags origin
for tag in $(
    git for-each-ref \
        --format='%(refname:strip=2)' \
        'refs/tags/**'
); do
    # Remove the remote copy
    git push -d origin "$tag"
    # Remove the local copy
    git tag -d "$tag"
done

The reason it issues one git call for each is because deleting multiple refs will exit on the first failure.
You can also exclude tags by glob pattern from the deletion, too, using --exclude. This makes it so you don't have to configure GitLab to protect any tags:
# Make sure all remote tags exist locally so we can iterate over them
git fetch --tags origin
for tag in $(
    git for-each-ref \
        --format='%(refname:strip=2)' \
        --exclude='refs/tags/v[0-9]*' \
        'refs/tags/**'
); do
    # Remove the remote copy
    git push -d origin "$tag"
    # Remove the local copy
    git tag -d "$tag"
done

